# Problems compiling with atomic functions

Tags: opencl, gpu

I'm trying to compile this openCl code:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics : enable

__kernel void nQueens( __global int * data, __global int * result, __local int * stack, __local int *stack_size, int board_size)
{
    atom_inc( stack_size );
}
```

And I get this error:

> Your OpenCL kernels failed to compile: Error: Code selection failed to
>   select: 0x5307370: i32,ch = AtomicLoadAdd 0x53072e8, 0x5303d68,
>   0x53011a8 <0x4edf478:0>  alignment=4
>
> Error: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

atom_inc is the 64 bit version and atomic_inc is the 32 bit version. Also stack_size should be declared volatile. Thus, since you are using 32 bit integers you should use atomic_inc instead.

From http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_inc.html :

int atomic_inc (volatile __local int *p )

"A 64-bit version of this function, atom_inc, is enabled by cl_khr_int64_base_atomics. "

Comment: Hey sorry for my late reply, I'm tot totally sure but it seams that my gpu does not accept atomic functions.

Thanks